# Angular 2. Tour-of-heroes package. Browser instance

Tags: angular

I need some indications please, I'm trying to find a way to set the project starting in Chrome not in IE. I don't have admin rights to change from system the default browser. Where, in node modules, I should modify to obtain that behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `bs-config.json` in your root folder and add this to it:

```
{
  "browser": "chrome"
}
```

For more startup and Browsersync related options you can look [here](https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-browser).

Comment: Or if it doesnt work, try `"browser": "google chrome"`. I have tried neither, but the browser-sync docs has an example which mentions "google chrome" https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-browser